# Does looking at monitors fatigue the eye muscles and/or affect overall fatigue?

Tags: eye

I will most likely spend a lot of my lifetime staring at (computer) monitors. This is necessary for my profession and technology of today requires us to look at monitors/screens more.

My question is this: Does looking at monitors fatigue the muscles around the eyes because they have to maintain a constant focus? Can this also increase fatigue?
If this is the case, I also wonder if this effect can be reduced by wearing glasses with a certain correction, adjusted to the distance between eyes and screen.

I hypothesize that the muscles can relax more, energy will be saved and the strain on the eyes is reduced. I'm certainly not an expert in anatomy however so I hope you can help me out.

Comment: I undeleted at your request. If you get a good answer, raise a flag on the other question so we can mark it as a dupe to point to the answer.